# Why useMemo don't recreate object when dependency change?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating simple nested comments system in React. Creating comment on backend and updating global comments state works fine. But new comment is not rendered, it appears only when i refresh browser. So problem is in useMemo hook. It does not re-create group object (which I use to group root and nested comments) every time comments state change as I expect it will. Can you help me? What I am doing wrong... Thanks.

```
const CommentContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
    comments: [],
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
}

const commentReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "loading":
            return { ...state, isLoading: true }
        case "comments/loaded":
            return { comments: action.payload, isLoading: false, error: null }
        case "comment/created":
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, comments: [...state.comments, action.payload], error: null }
        case "rejected":
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const CommentContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(commentReducer, initialState);
    const { comments } = state;

    const commentsByParentId = useMemo(() => {
        // Grouping comments by rootComments(comments where parent === undefined) and nestedComments of rootComments
        // rootComments -> comment.parent === undefined -> { undefined: [{...}, {...}, ...] }
        // nestedComments of rootComment -> comment.parent === parentId -> { parentId: [{...}, {...}, ...] }
        const group = {};
        comments.forEach(comment => {
            // if there is parentId in group then use that array else use new empty array
            group[comment.parent] ||= [];
            group[comment.parent].push(comment);
        });
        return group;
    }, [comments]);

    console.log(comments);  // showing new comments array with new comment
    console.log("Root comments: ",commentsByParentId[null]);  // showing old comments array

    const createComment = async (content, postId, parentId = null) => {
        dispatch({ type: "loading" });
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/${postId}/comments`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                credentials: 'include',
                body: JSON.stringify({ content, parentId })
            });
            const json = await response.json();

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(json.message);
            }
            if (response.ok) {
                dispatch({ type: 'comment/created', payload: json });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ type: "rejected", payload: error.message });
        }
    }

    return (
        <CommentContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch, createComment, rootComments: commentsByParentId[null] }}>
            {children}
        </CommentContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I don't have any ideas...

Comment: In your rendered element it might be worth adding a JSON.stringify(comments) just to ensure that your dispatches are running correctly and your state is getting updated.

Comment: Did you try using directly `state.comments` as dependency?

Comment: Is it `comment.parent` or `comment.parentId`?

Comment: Your usage of `useMemo` seems fine. Can you make a [mcve], please? What does the create-comment fetch request return? How do you use the provided context? How do you load the existing comments? What is different when you refresh the page?

Comment: Is the ```comment.parent ``` null instead of undefined? ```rootComments -> comment.parent === undefined -> { undefined: [{...}, {...}, ...] }```  I'm looking for undefined in the your comment, so I'm guessing.